# Two html canvases on top of each other centered horizontally on browser window

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, easeljs

I am trying to use two html5 canvas objects on top of each other, in order to use the one of them as a static background, and the other as a stage that all the action occurs.

The purpose is that the background is larger than the foreground canvas and a static image, so projecting the background once and not rendering it constantly is going to save resources.

I would like both of the objects to be centered horizontally on the center of the browser window always (even if window is resized), and i need some help for the CSS. Currently the two canvases have the same height but not width.

Let me point that the canvases are resized (scaled by height) each time the browser window is resized, so that vertically no part of the scene is clipped/cropped, but horizontally, there is no such restriction. 
So when the browser window gets smaller in width than the canvases, the get cropped left and right proportionally, and they keep being centered in the middle of the page.

My code is almost complete, as it scales all objects and crops the scene based on the browser window size, but i cannot find a way to center the canvases horizontally.

If you would like to test the code in JS Bin, i would suggest to choose the live preview mode (click the far right arrow button) to see the results in full screen, and play with the window size.

[JS Bin code preview](http://jsbin.com/jisuqisefi/edit?html,js,output)

Below are visual results of the current output and the desired one

[image: Current Output]

[image: Desired output]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the big canvas is just a static background, why even use HTML5 canvas? Just use a div with a `background-image`.

Comment: Tried to but couldn't find a way to scale the background-image proportionally to the canvas object. The result was wrongly positioned objects in some (not all) window sizes. So decieded that was not possible... :)

Comment: I also expect that a static canvas uses the same resources, as a backround-image, and i could have a better control over it, if i need to add elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, and I'm including a snippet implementation below.

```
canvas#front, canvas#back {
    position: absolute;
    /* Use calc to make sure that browser without transform support
     * (that therefore also dont support calc) don't 
     * actually move your elements. */
    left: calc(50%);
    top: calc(50%);
    /* Don't forget to prefix. */
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 1;
}
canvas#back { z-index: 0; }
```

```js
document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){resizeCanvas();}, true);

var sscale = 1.0;
canvas_back = document.getElementById("canvas_back");
stage2 = new createjs.Stage(canvas_back); 
stage2.autoClear = true;
my_ticker2 = createjs.Ticker.on("tick",stage2); 
   
this.back = new createjs.Bitmap("http://i.imgur.com/VcDqpBW.png"); 
stage2.addChild(this.back);
   
canvas_front = document.getElementById("canvas_front");
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas_front); 
stage.autoClear = true;
createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF_SYNCHED; createjs.Ticker.framerate = 120;
my_ticker = createjs.Ticker.on("tick",stage); 
this.ob1 = new createjs.Bitmap("http://i.imgur.com/3toyiJo.png"); 
this.ob1.x=Math.floor(canvas_front.width/2); 
this.ob1.y = Math.floor(canvas_front.height/2);
stage.addChild(this.ob1);
resizeCanvas();

function resizeCanvas()
{
 var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;//window.screen.availHeight;
 console.log("SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, canvas_back.height", SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, canvas_back.height);
 ratio = (SCREEN_HEIGHT/canvas_back.height);

 sscale = (sscale*ratio); console.log("ratio,sscale : ", ratio,sscale);
   
 stage.scaleX = sscale;
 stage.scaleY = sscale;
 canvas_back.width = Math.min(canvas_back.width*ratio);
 canvas_back.height = Math.min(canvas_back.height*ratio);
 console.log("canvas width/height : " , canvas_back.width, canvas_back.height);
 stage2.scaleX = sscale;
 stage2.scaleY = sscale;
 
 canvas_front.width = Math.min(canvas_front.width*ratio);
 canvas_front.height = Math.min(canvas_front.height*ratio);
   
 /*if(canvas_back.width > SCREEN_WIDTH)
 { */
  console.log("canvas width bigger than screen width");
  document.documentElement.scrollLeft = ((document.body.scrollWidth - document.body.clientWidth) / 2);
  document.body.scrollLeft = ((document.body.scrollWidth - document.body.clientWidth) / 2);    
 /*}*/
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#canvas_back, #canvas_front {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.05.21.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas_back" height="256" width="512"> asdf </canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas_front" height="256" width="384"> asdf </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Please keep in mind that I also highly simplified your HTML to just contain the canvasses, this is to avoid any confusion, but the technique should work. Lastyle, when defining a `width` and `height`, only use `%` as a unit, otherwise just use a number as it is automatically going to use `pixels`. It just looks cleaner.

Like @Rvervuurt said, though, if it's not going use any features of `canvas` you might as well draw it as a static image and render it as a background-image, centred with `background-position: 50% 50%` - the overlaying code will still work, but your page will be a little bit snappier as there's no canvas to keep track of at all.

### Update: Use `<img />` and/or `background-image`

Below is an implementation of using a simple image or background-image. I have simplified your code a bit (made the canvas simple a drawn square in order for everything to be as obvious as possible).

```js
var cf = document.getElementById('canvas_front');
cf.width = 100;
cf.height = 100;
var ctx = cf.getContext('2d');
ctx.rect(0,0,100,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
* { margin: 0;padding: 0; }

html, body { height: 100%; }

#canvas_front, #img_back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
#canvas_back { display: none; }
#img_back { z-index: 1; }
#bg_back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="bg_back" style='background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=75&bg=880000&txtclr=green&txt=1000×1000&w=1000&h=1000);'></div>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=A+Large+Background&w=1000&h=800" id="img_back" height="256" width="512" />
  <canvas id="canvas_front" height="256" width="384"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well as i said above to @Rveruurt. But please elaborate, i am also interested in that solution also. What do you mean by saying : "a little bit snappier as there's no canvas to keep track of at all"...?

Comment: Well, if you are going to serve what is essentially a static image, why use canvas to serve it? Just use an `<img>` tag instead. I know you want to use JS to draw stuff, but if the drawing isn't going to be changed in any meaninful way you might as well draw it in Paint and use the exported data. Browsers are very well optimised at displaying static images, canvas is for more than that. You can even draw it in the canvas and then export your image and save it to your computer as a resource. For that check here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

Comment: I would use either backround-image or <img> tag but as hard as i tried, i couldn't scale them like the way i did with the canvas.
Of course if you say that i can use CSS's background-image or <img> tag the same way you used the canvas_back element, i would be happy to do it!

Comment: Yeah you can easily replace the canvas with an img, as long as your CSS points at it and uses the rules above, you'll be fine!

Comment: By the way, the snippet you provided works fine, except you need to remove the body.scrollLeft and document.scrollLeft lines.

Also if it's not big trouble, i would like you to add the solution using background-image (preffered) or <img> because everything i tried the past 30 minutes is not working for me...

HUGE thanks!

Comment: I am a little confused by the second snippet, but anyway the point seems to be (regarding the background-image) to use : "background-size : auto 100%;" which scales the image automatically to fit the window height.

Comment: Not really, the point is the `50% 50%` and absolute positioning. When you know the sizes you can center things, then it doesnt matter what size your image is, the pixel at 50%, 50% will always be in the middle. Good luck.